# Alter Stored Procedure in SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication

How do I, properly, `ALTER` a StoredProcedure in a SQL 2005 Merge Replication?

I just need to add a Column.  I already successfully added it to the Table and I now need to add it to a SP.  I did so but now it will not synchronize with the following error -->

`Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 213)`

### Add my comment below here for easier viewing

Yes the table change was already replicated. THEN the Stored PRocedure quit working as the columns were off so I did an ALTER on the stored procedure and tried to replicate that. Now it won't sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the table change been replicated yet?  I'm not a replication expert but that might be your problem.

Comment: yes the table change was already replicated.  THEN the Stored PRocedure quit working as the columns were off so I did an ALTER on the stored procedure and tried to replicate that.  Now it won't sync...I am a dead man.... :(